# Android Jetpack Compose: "No static method setInitialSurroundingText in class EditorInfoCompat" on OutlinedTextField click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement a search bar and a box just below to search & display an address list using Jetpack Compose (my first UI using Kotlin).
This is how I did it :

```kotlin
    @Composable
    private fun LocalizationScreen(
        addressList: List<String>,
        onSearchValueChanged: (query: String) -> Unit
    ) {
       var isSearching by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
       displayText = remember { mutableStateOf("") }.value

       Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
       ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
               value = displayText,
               onValueChange = {
                   isSearching = it.isNotEmpty()
                   onSearchValueChanged.invoke(it)
               },
               label = { Text(text = "Adresse") }
           )
           AddressListBox(addressList = addressList, isSearching)
      }
```

When I launch the app, it displays a basic `OutlineTextField`. But when I **click** on it, the **app crashes** with the following stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setInitialSurroundingText(Landroid/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V in class Landroidx/core/view/inputmethod/EditorInfoCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.view.inputmethod.EditorInfoCompat' appears in /data/app/~~****************==/bla.blac.bla.debug-TLWFWI3WdhzpXiEL2uW_8g==/base.apk)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextInputServiceAndroid_androidKt.update(TextInputServiceAndroid.android.kt:335)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextInputServiceAndroid.createInputConnection(TextInputServiceAndroid.android.kt:104)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onCreateInputConnection(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:945)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:2250)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$DelegateImpl.startInput(InputMethodManager.java:699)
        at android.view.ImeFocusController.checkFocus(ImeFocusController.java:192)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:2431)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(InputMethodManager.java:1892)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(InputMethodManager.java:1815)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.InputMethodManagerImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodManager.kt:62)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextInputServiceAndroid.keyboardVisibilityEventLoop(TextInputServiceAndroid.android.kt:189)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextInputServiceAndroid$keyboardVisibilityEventLoop$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

I am using compose version `1.0.1` with kotlin `1.5.21`. Also the compose compiler version `1.0.1` :

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.1"
    }
```

I already tried the usual "Invalide caches and restart" and downgraded compose version from `1.0.2` and kotlin version from `1.5.30` (which [requires an alpha version of the compose compiler](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#version_110_2))

Does anyone has an idea of what is happening here ? (Thank you for reading this far)

Comment: what's the version of `androidx.core:core-ktx` or `androidx.core:core`?

Comment: I am using version `1.6.0` of `androidx.core:core-ktx`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out I needed to **declare all compose dependencies in my app module** too (yeah I am in a multi module project. Sorry I missed this information).

So in my sub-module `build.gradle` I had :

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.1.0-alpha04"
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.1.0-alpha04"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

And in my main module `build.gradle` I now have the same (which  I didn't have before) :

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.1.0-alpha04"
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.1.0-alpha04"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping this question around along with your own answer. For me the problem was failing to define the configurations for buildFeatures and composeOptions for my module… This Q&A helped me out of my own blindness!